# Iterating on the table using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I don't understand why x-path doesn't working in table. I'm trying to iter table from the website I found xpath but Eclipse told me:

> "Unable to find element with xpath".

Should I find xpath in tables another way?

Website URL: https://www.oferty.net/mieszkania/szukaj?ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btransaction%5D=1&ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btext%5D=dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie

I try to read one offer for example:

```
String urlwyniki ="https://www.oferty.net/mieszkania/szukaj?ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btransaction%5D=1&ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btext%5D=dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie";
driver.get(urlwyniki);
String xpathResult = "//html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td";
String sCellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathResult)).getText();
System.out.print(sCellValue);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try with x-path '//tbody/tr/td'

Comment: Could You wrote whole xpath as You think. I have tried several methods by classname:

Comment: Could You wrote whole xpath as You think. I have tried several methods by classname:  table class  "properties". If I use it I got the list of all offers. But when I want to iterate it eclipse write Number of rows in webtable = 0.

Comment: Which table? Which `text` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below code to iterate all cell value in the table. It may help you.

```
String urlwyniki ="https://www.oferty.net/mieszkania/szukaj?ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btype%5D=1&ps%5Btransaction%5D=1&ps%5Blocation%5D%5Btext%5D=dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie";
driver.get(urlwyniki);
String xpathResult = "//table/tbody/tr/td";
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathResult));
List<WebElement> cols=new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
    System.out.print("Row value: "+i);
    cols=rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement col:cols)
        System.out.print("cell value "+col.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much